# how to perform substring extraction and substitution in tcl

Tags: string, tcl

I am trying to extract a substring from a string in Tcl. I wrote the code and able to do it, but I was wondering if there is any other efficient way to do it. So the exact problem is I have a string

> `name_ext_10a.string_10a.string.string.string`

and I want to extract "`name_ext`", and then remove that "`_`" and replace it with "`.`"; I finally want the output to be "`name.ext`". I wrote something like this:

```
set _File "[string replace $_File [string last "_" $_File] [string length $_File] "" ]"
set _File "[string replace $_File [string last "_" $_File] [string length $_File] "" ]"
set _File "[string replace $_File [string last "_" $_File] [string last "_" $_File] "." ]"
```

which gives me the exact output I want, but I was wondering if there is any other efficient way to do this in Tcl.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could split that filename using underscore as a separator, and then join the first 2 elements with a dot:

```
% set f name_ext_10a.string_10a.string.string.string
name_ext_10a.string_10a.string.string.string
% set out [join [lrange [split $f _] 0 1] .]
name.ext
```

**EDIT**

So if "name" can have an arbitrary number of underscores:

```
set f "foo_bar_baz_ext_10a.string_10a.string.string.string"
set pieces [split $f _]
set name [join [lrange $pieces 0 end-3] _]
set out [join [list $name [lindex $pieces end-2]] .]  ;#==> foo_bar_baz.ext
```

But this is getting complex. One regex should suffice -- I assume "string" can be any sequence of non-underscore chars.

```
set string {[^_]+}
set regex "^(.+)_($string)_10a.${string}_10a.$string.$string.$string\$"
regexp $regex $f -> name ext
set out "$name.$ext"    ;#==> foo_bar_baz.ext
```

Comment: yes but the problem is the string "name" can itself have any number of underscores. So what doesn't change is "_ext_10a.str_10a.str.str.str" pattern. So that's why i tried to replace the string after last two underscores with empty string so that i will get "name_ext" and than change this last underscore with a dot.

Answer (score 2):

One way to do the extraction is with `regsub`:

```
regsub {^([^_]+)_([^_]+)_.*} $_File {\1.\2} _File
```

The regular expression contains `([^_]+)` components, which match a sequence of non-underscore characters, plus an anchor and some underscores, and a trailing non-capturing `.*` which matches everything else (so we can discard it). The `regsub` replaces that (which is the whole string) with the concatenation of the two matched non-underscore sections with a `.` between, and writes it back to the `_File` variable where the string came from.

*Note that I put the regular expression and replacement in braces.* This is because they contain Tcl metacharacters (square brackets and backslashes) which I want Tcl to pass into `regsub` verbatim.

Comment: Thanks Donal, but problem is that the "name" can itself have any number of underscores so the only pattern that doesn't change is "_ext_10a.str_10a.str.str.str" so that is why i searched for the 2nd last underscore and replace everything after that with empty string and the replace "_ext" with ".ext"

Comment: @Puneet That sort of detail is really important; regular expressions are very dependent on having a correct understanding of what is to be matched.