# TCL - Fetch string between strings

Tags: regex, tcl

I have a large chunk of data and would like to extract a value of a particular field using TCL regexp.

```
ip="1.2.3.4" protocol="SFTP" username="abcd"
```

Need to extract the word SFTP without double quotes, the former and later fields can be ip,username or something else. So regexp has to use the word protocol as reference.

Comment: See [how to perform substring extraction and substitution in tcl](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12168576/how-to-perform-substring-extraction-and-substitution-in-tcl) and 
[Substring extraction in TCL](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32400747/substring-extraction-in-tcl)

Answer (score 1):

In this case, I'd use:

```
regexp {\yprotocol="(.*?)"} $theString -> theProtocol
```

***However,*** if this is parsing XML then I'd *actually* use an XML handling extension like tDOM.